# express::server::routerTypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, typeerror

I don't understand why i have this error when i try to get the length of an element in my post request, i try to remove the yarn.lock file and remove node_moduls and download it again, but it don't work can any one help me please !!!

my code:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { first_name, last_name, email, pass1, pass2 } = req.body;
    const errors = []
    if (!first_name || !last_name || !email || !pass1 || !pass2)
        errors.push({ msg: 'please fill all fields' })
    var name = first_name.concat(' ')
    name = name.concat(last_name)
    if (pass1 !== pass2)
        errors.push({ msg: 'password don\'t match' })
    if (pass1.length() < 8)
        errors.push({ msg: 'message length should be upper than 8' })

    if (errors.length() > 0) {
        res.send("error")
    } else {
        res.send(req.body)
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that pass1 is not defined, so it gives you that error, that you can't call .length of undefined. try `console.log(pass1)` and see its value. 
also you should use `(pass1.length < 8)` and `(errors.length > 0)` because
length is not a function it's a property, it will also give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling string.length(), while length is a property and not a function I believe. Try removing () and maybe console.log(pass1) to make sure.